# Is the exclamation sign on the settings icon a bug or am I missing something?

Tags: sky-force-reloaded

After the [latest update (version 1.45)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.SkyForceReloaded2016&hl=en) an exclamation mark did appear on the "settings" icon in the main screen. I can't find what it points to. I have entered all of the submenus in the settings screen but this icon doesn't disappear from the main screen. I've thought that it was there to inform about the new aircraft and began to collect the pink parts but it didn't change anything either.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinite Dreams must be watching this tag here on Arqade :) They've just released [an update](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.SkyForceReloaded2016) which solved this problem.

> What's new in 1.46:
>   - fixed problem with game freezing on level start (on some devices),
>   - **exclamation mark is now correctly displayed in the main menu.**